# Getting the nightly version of a stable release

Tags: rust

My current understanding is that stable releases are subsets of nightly (essentially with every feature flag turned off), given this is there a way to get the corresponding nightly release for a stable release?

Specifically would `rustc 1.62.0-nightly` (without any feature flags) have identical behavior to `rustc 1.62.0`?

Comment: I'd think this is not strictly true as beta and stable often get backported fixes from newer versions of nightly.

Answer (score 2):

Stable releases do not use the same code as nightly ones. Nightly releases are built off of the `master` branch, whereas stable releases have their own branch off of nightly with fixes backported. [See also the page for how Rust's Git branching works](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-07-nightly-rust.html).

The `version` subcommand or `--version` argument to most rust tools (`cargo`, `rustc`, etc) should print the git hash along with the version info, which will tell you exactly what version of the source it was built against. Additionally, stable releases are tagged in the Git repo.